# How to enable on-page edition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to enable a part of page to be editable once a button is clicked? (i.e. edit & read on the same page)

For example, when you click "edit" on this page (the page you are reading now), the title and body is editable (they change to input elements), it doesn't redirect to the edit page in order to change the title or body. So, I want to enable instant edition.

It seems like that it has to do with jquery, but I don't how to achieve this.

Comment: this is a multi-step process with lots of complications if you want to retain the edits

Comment: When you click edit, you are actually being taken to a completely different page, with the same content inside form elements. That content is stored in a database and populated into the HTML by a server side program like PHP, or Ruby. Try reading about [building a simple dynamic app](https://css-tricks.com/app-from-scratch-1-design/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden `input`s and show them when you click on button `edit` and hide the content readable in same time, like example bellow.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.edit-page').on('click', function(){
    $('.title, .body').hide(); //Hide readable part
    $('.edit-title, .edit-body').show(); //Show editable part
})
```

```css
.edit{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Readable part -->
<span class='title'>Your title HERE</span>
<input type="text" class="edit edit-title" value='Your title HERE'/>
</br>

<!-- Editable part -->
<span class='body'>Your body HERE</span>
<textarea class="edit edit-body">Your body HERE</textarea>

</br></br>

<button class="edit-page">Edit</button>
```